# emotion detection for messages

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I'm working on a project that requires NLP. The scenario involves two or more participants exchanging messages in a chat app. I want to use am NLP/ML model to auto-tag message for the participants' emotions as the conversation is happening (e.g happy, sad, anger, frustrated, I'm not looking for sentiment analysis). My prior knowledge of NLP is limited, and I had a hard time finding the right model to use.

I found this repo [conv-emotion](https://github.com/SenticNet/conv-emotion) and spent almost two days trying to make it work. Currently reaching out to the authors for help. I like their repo is because it's the model is applied on a conversation level. But unfortunately, their README isn't well written.

Any suggestions going forward? Do you know any model or even API that I can use? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

For sentiment analysis, I think to go for Gated CNN will get you quite a good result. And pair it with some rules and you'd be fine. Try reading this paper : https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1234/